# Flutter build Error after upgrading flutter

Tags: android, flutter

My Flutter android app was running without any problems but I upgraded Flutter to 3.3.4 and now I am having the following Error while building app bundle (and apk). Please help me.

> The argument type 'EdgeInsets' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Margins?'.

Code:

```
style: {
                    'body': Style(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      fontSize: const FontSize(16.0),
                      lineHeight: const LineHeight(1.4),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    'figure': Style(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.zero, padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
                  },
```

[image: Error]

and another error:

> Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const
> expression is expected. Try using a constructor or factory that is
> 'const'.

```
                    fontSize: const FontSize(12.0),
                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

[image: Another Error]

Comment: It's not because you're upgrading flutter version, please put your code where the error consists

Comment: style: {
                    'body': Style(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      fontSize: const FontSize(16.0),
                      lineHeight: const LineHeight(1.4),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    'figure': Style(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.zero, padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
                  },

Answer (score 1):

Replace `fontSize: const FontSize(12.0)` with `fontSize: 12`

Post the saved_articles_tile.dart snippet for more help.

Comment: style: { 'body': Style( margin: EdgeInsets.zero, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, fontSize: const FontSize(16.0), lineHeight: const LineHeight(1.4), color: Colors.white, textAlign: TextAlign.center, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, ), 'figure': Style( margin: EdgeInsets.zero, padding: EdgeInsets.zero), },

Comment: What is the exact widget you are using?